# Exclusion rects not shifting text properly with NSTextView/UITextView

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, textkit

I have an `NSTextView` with some exclusion rects so I can shift the text vertically without having to resort to adding newlines to the string. However, I've noticed that the exclusion rect is rather limited or perhaps even buggy because I cannot shift the text vertically more than ~45% of the textview's height. I have found a workaround where I increase the textview's height by 2x but this feels gross and I'd rather do it "properly"

[image]

In the image above, I have three text views (from left to right)

1. Programmatically without encapsulating it inside an `NSScrollView`, 2x height
2. Programmatically with `NSScrollView` encapsulation. 2x height
3. Using interface builder, regular height.

The exclusion rect is drawn with a `CAShapeLayer` and you can see that "hello world new world" isn't properly positioned outside of the exclusion rect.

I tried all three examples to make sure I wasn't missing something with regards to IB default settings or the dynamics of the text view when encapsulated in an `NSScrollView` (Im new to AppKit and TextKit), however all 3 examples exhibit the same bug.

### Code to update the text exclusion rect

(Each time the slider moves on the bottom right, it will update their text rect)

```
label.stringValue = "excl: \(sender.integerValue): height: \(view.frame.height)"
print(sender.integerValue)

let exclHeight: CGFloat = CGFloat(slider.integerValue)


[aTextView, bTextView, cTextView]
  .compactMap { $0 }
  .forEach {
    let rect = CGRect(
      x: 5,
      y: 5,
      width: aTextView.frame.width - 10,
      height: exclHeight)
    $0.wantsLayer = true
    $0.textContainer?.exclusionPaths.removeAll()
    $0.textContainer?.exclusionPaths.append(.init(rect: rect))
    $0.layer?.sublayers?.forEach {
      $0.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }

    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.frame = rect
    layer.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
    layer.borderWidth = 1
    layer.borderColor = NSColor.white.cgColor
    $0.layer?.addSublayer(layer)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the exclusionPath is before the first line.

Just playing around with the parameters, a two line sample text with the rect `y` positioned after the first line works without any problems.

So it looks like the issue is calculating the container height when it starts with a exclusionPaths in `-[NSLayoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:]`

```
@interface LOLayoutManager : NSLayoutManager
@end

@implementation LOLayoutManager

- (NSRect)usedRectForTextContainer:(NSTextContainer *)container
{
    NSRect rect = [super usedRectForTextContainer:container];
    NSRect newRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, NSMaxX(rect), NSMaxY(rect));
    return newRect;
}

@end
```

Instead of returning `y` position from the exclusionPaths and the line fragments height, this returns a big rect starting at `0, 0`. This should work as long as the NSTextView only contains one text container.

Comment: Using this subclass of `NSLayoutManager` did the trick. I will just mention the API to use this subclass is:
```
textView.textContainer?.replaceLayoutManager(LayoutManager());
```